# Correctly align vertical text on a baseline in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment

I'm proud to announce that I have a large number of PGFplots in my document.

But ... I have a small problem with the vertical alignment of text throughout my plots.

What's the easiest way to align text on a baseline in PGFPlots? I'm particularly interested in alignment of text in multi-column legends, but also on axes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  y post scale=0.2,
  legend style={at={(0.5,1.02)},anchor=south},
  legend columns=3,
  xmin=0,
  ytick={one,two,eight},
  symbolic y coords={one,two,eight},
  bar width=7pt,
  enlarge y limits=0.3 
]

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(1,one)};
\addlegendentry{one}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(2,two)};
\addlegendentry{two}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(8,eight)};
\addlegendentry{eight}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here you see that in the legend, text is centred "mid" according to the height of the text block (see `one` floating higher than the baseline of `two` due to being shorter, and ditto `two` to `eight`), not according to a natural text baseline. This is also true of the *y*-axis (and would be true of the *x*-axis also).

I could fix this by appending phantom text like `tg` to equalise the text heights of my various labels, but this would introduce redundant horizontal space and I have a large number of plots and hope that particular hack is not necessary.

I would love a solution I could stick in the `\pgfplotsset{ ... }` in the head of my document that would apply across all plots, for legends and *x* & *y* axes, but am open to suggestions.

Anyone know how this text alignment could be best achieved universally?

Comment: FWIW, my back-up solution is: `legend style={font=\scshape}`. ... any excuse to use small caps. ^.^

Comment: For the legend adding `\strut` or (preferable) a custom `\mystrut` (e.g. `\def\mystrut{\vphantom{hg}}`) works (all text boxes have the same depth and height now). This probably would work for the y axis, too. Maybe there's a `font=` key for these things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> For the legend adding `\strut` or (preferable) a custom `\mystrut` (e.g. `\def\mystrut{\vphantom{hg}}`) works (all text boxes have the same depth and height now). This probably would work for the y axis, too. Maybe there's a `font=` key for these things?

Oh, yes there is: `legend style` and `y tick label style`.

I used `\vphantom{hg}` here because `h` and `g` are the highest and deepest letters in your example. For a more general solution (actual text, different fonts) I'd use the very high `\strut` or a longer `\vphantom` argument.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\mystrut{\vphantom{hg}}
%\def\mystrut{\strut}
\pgfplotsset{
    legend style={font=\mystrut},
    y tick label style={font=\mystrut}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  y post scale=0.2,
  legend style={at={(0.5,1.02)},anchor=south},
  legend columns=3,
  xmin=0,
  ytick={one,two,eight},
  symbolic y coords={one,two,eight},
  bar width=7pt,
  enlarge y limits=0.3 
]

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(1,one)};
\addlegendentry{one}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(2,two)};
\addlegendentry{two}

\addplot+[xbar] coordinates {(8,eight)};
\addlegendentry{eight}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought that phantom text would add redundant horizontal white-space, but it appears not so this works well!

Comment: @badroit `\phantom` adds vertical and horizontal, `\hphantom` only horizontal, `\vphantom` only vertical space.