# Align label with ticklabel in ticklabel cs in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to place the xlabel for a plot on the same baseline the xticklabels. To do that I changed the xlabel style/at key to (ticklabel cs: 1), the rightmost position of the ticklabel coordinate system. However, the label is not on the same baseline, but has a y-offset compared to the tick labels. Note that, I applied an x-shift, to overlay the character 'm' with the tick-label '1' so that the offset can be easily seen.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel = {m},
    xlabel style = {
      at = { (ticklabel cs: 1) },
      anchor = south,
      xshift = -15pt,
      %yshift = -0.2pt,
    },
    ]
    \addplot coordinates { (0,1) (1,0) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Since I can only post two links, I won't show an picture of the compiled pdf. Instead I will show zoomed in pictures of the axis label overlaid on the tick label. You can easily see there is an offset between the baseline of the tick label and the axis label:

[image: Zoomed in picture showing x label and tick label do not have the same baseline.]

If I apply a y-offset manually via the x label style (commented-out shift in the MWE), I can align the baselines of the tick labels and the axis label:

[image: x label and tick label aligned manually.]

However, the required y-shift changes with the selected font and various other plot settings. How can I reliably vertically align the axis label with the tick labels?

Thank you in advance for your time and suggestions.

Comment: That is not enough shift. If I select another font, it is totally off.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer my question. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84127/correctly-align-vertical-text-on-a-baseline-in-pgfplots?rq=1), or rather the answer got me thinking that 'm' is way smaller than '1' and thus I need `\vphantom` to align them properly. This was not the case, since both characters do not extend beyond the baseline and are anchored `south`. However, when applying the `\vphantom`-command to the `style/font`-key did not work, I also enabled `draw, line width = 1pt` to both label styles and everything was aligned properly. After a bit of testing I now think that `xlabel` and `tick label` have different line widths for their nodes and that is why they are not vertically aligned. Setting both line widths to 0 aligns everything properly. `\vphantom` might be needed if something extends below the baseline, like 'g', for example.

Edit: Testing another font, I found I need both: setting the line width and applying `\vphantom`.

Comment: Simply kill the `outer sep` value as in     `xlabel style = {
      at = { (ticklabel cs: 1) },
      anchor = south,
      xshift = -15pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
    }`

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried `outer sep = 0pt` for `x label style` only as well as together with `x tick label style`.

Comment: Saying simply "doesn't work" is useless. In your example code it works.

Comment: You are correct. I was doubting myself for a while there. Simply adding `\usepackage{unicode-math}` suffices to break the `outer sep = 0pt`-solution (the 'm' is set too low). I assumed simply loading the package did not change anything (after all the font is the same). Not sure why or how this breaks things.