# pgfplot - keep legends widthin \linewidth when the are set outside

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend, size

I'm using pgfplots, but i want to have my legends next to the plot.

This is easy by setting *legend style* and *anchor*. But i also want the plot to be as big as possible.

So if my labels are to long, they will not fit in the document.

See following code and plot:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{grid=both,width=\linewidth}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(1.02,1)},anchor=north west}]
  \addplot {x};
  \addlegendentry{long long long long long long}
  \addplot {x*2};
  \addlegendentry{not long}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have found a solution!
there is a usepackage called *tikzscale* which makes it possible to use *includegraphics* with tikz. The usepackage need to be instaled first though, which I did through *MikTex package manager*

Here is an example on how it works:

first you make your plots in .tikz files:

**temp.tikz**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(1.02,1)},anchor=north west}]
  \addplot {x};
  \addlegendentry{short short}
  \addplot {x*2};
  \addlegendentry{not long}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**temp2.tikz**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(1.02,1)},anchor=north west}]
  \addplot {x};
  \addlegendentry{long long long long long long}
  \addplot {x*2};
  \addlegendentry{not long}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

then include them to your .tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\pgfplotsset{grid=both} 
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=10cm]{temp.tikz}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=10cm]{temp2.tikz}

\end{document}
```

which gives following result:
[image]

Comment: So how do you want the page to look like?  Obviously, `tikz` cannot buy you larger paper...

Comment: First, use \noindent.  Second, try \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}

Comment: @jarauh I really don't have many demand on the layout of this document. It just need to fit in a A4 paper.Two possible ways i can think of is: Scaling the with of the pgfplot depending of the length of  the labels. Or somehow making the legend show single labels in multiple lines

Comment: @JohnKormylo \noindent did shift the plot a little bit to the left, but isn't enough.  And though \resizebox do the job, it scales everything, including the text, which doesn't look nice.

Comment: Alas \addlegendentry{\parbox ...} overlaps.  However, you can create your own legend.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278530/how-i-can-customize-a-legend-on-pgfplots/278538?s=2|0.0000#278538

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP has answered the question himself in the edit of the question.